# How can i switch between phone and pc in Xaml designer in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, xaml-designer

I recently installed VS2015, and one of the things that is changed since VS2013 is that the dropdown menu for switching the xaml designer between phone and PC for shared views in Windows 8.1 universal apps is gone.

Switching startup project does not seem to affect the designer either. I'm wondering if the menu is somewhere else, or if there is a way to get this feature back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer myself. The dropdown menu in the .cs file also controls the corresponding xaml view, instead of two different menus as in the previous version. I feel a little bit silly now for not seeing that earlier.